# Partially applied equality constraint

Tags: haskell, types, type-constraints

Consider the following:

```
class (a ~ b) => Equal a b
instance (a ~ b) => Equal a b
```

Lets say I later have a data type:

```
data D (c :: * -> Constraint) where
  D :: Proxy c -> D c
```

Then something like this is valid:

```
D (Proxy :: (Proxy (Equal Int)))
```

My question is, is there any way to write `Equal` other than the repetitive class/instance notation I've used?

It seems that when I define `Equal` as a type family `Equal Int` doesn't work because it's an incomplete application.

The class/instance hack looks bad but at least it works, but is there any other maybe cleaner way of achieving this?

Note I'll be using constraints more complex than equality in my actual code, I just thought this would be a good example.

Comment: I guess `Proxy ((~) Int)` does not work, but it would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a class at all, you can just use `(~)` in prefix notation.

There is a bug in GHC 8.0.1 which sometimes makes it crash, but it is just a bug, and it's fixed in 8.0.2. The class / instance combo you're describing is indeed an effective workaround for this bug.

If you do not need backwards compatibility with 8.0.1, you can use `(~) Int` or `Proxy ((~) Int)` directly.