# Partially applied type family

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, type-families

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526616/partially-applied-equality-constraint) where an answer revealed partially applying the `(~)` type operator is allowed.

Consider the following (silly) type family:

```
type family SillyT a b :: Constraint

data D (c :: * -> Constraint) where
  D :: Proxy c -> D c
```

Then something like this is not valid:

```
D (Proxy :: (Proxy (SillyT Int)))
```

But if I wrap `SillyT` in a class like so:

```
class SillyT a b => SillyC a b
instance SillyT a b => SillyC a b
```

Then I can do this:

```
D (Proxy :: (Proxy (SillyC Int)))
```

And everything works fine. However wrapping in a class does seem a bit silly and repetitive, but is this the only way to partially apply a type family?

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but maybe the problem is that you choose the kind constraint for the return of your family. Constraints can only appear in the left hand side of `=>`.

Comment: What else could it be other than `Constraint` if all the type instances are Constraints? Like say `type instance SillyT Int a = Num a` to make a silly example

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your other question slightly. I think in this more general case the class-wrapping you're doing is adequate, and indeed I've been using the same approach quite often to be able to trick GHC into accepting partially applied constraints. In some cases you may be able to do entirely without the type family, given you have the class. But not always.

Comment: It should be noted that this does not really allow you to 'partially apply' your type family - if you had `instance SillyT Int a = Num a` then `SillyC Int` does not reduce to `Num`. This is the operative difference between families and injective type constructors (i.e. `data`, `newtype`, and `class`) - the former reduces immediately, but cannot be partially applied, while the latter only reduces when fully applied, but 'partial applications' are valid, but only in the sense that a partial application is a syntactically valid type.

Comment: @user2407038 Not quite sure why you're saying this isn't partial application. Partially applied functions also do (in general) not reduce unless you pass sufficiently many arguments.

Answer (score -1):

These two definitions you mention:
`type family SillyT a b :: Constraint` and `class ... => SillyC a b` are very, very different from the perspective of Haskell's type checker.

If you see the former one the only thing you know is that you get `Constraint` after applying two type variables, but you don't tell GHC what happens after applying only one. You should be able to define `SillyT` as `type family SillyT a :: * -> Constraint` and then it tells GHC much more.

Think about it like about constructor variables. If you tell GHC that something is a `Functor`, GHC knows that it's "shape" is `f a`, where `a` is a last parameter to some `f`. You have to tell GHC that it could analyse the result of `SillyT` in the same way, so GHC could be sure, that it always can access the last parameter looking at the result type.

Type classes, on the other hand, are a little more expressive here. They ARE a type, not a type transformation (like type families) and GHC can "pattern match" on their variables, so you don't encounter here the above limitation. Moreover, type classes allow you defining overlapping instances, which is not possible when using type families. However, functional dependencies are less flexible than type families, because unless GHC supports impredicative contexts, it's very hard to get rid of unnecessary free type variables using type deps.

I hope it clarifies some things :)

Comment: I think it does, but just to confirm, is the approach I'm using sensible or is there a better way?

Comment: You should not need to make type families and wrap them in classes in this way, because it generally makes no sense. I could tell you more if you tell about a real use case. Sometimes it could be profitable, but rather as a hack than a right solution. Everything  depends on the use case.

Comment: I downvoted. There's a lot of text here, but even as a Haskell expert I'm having a tough time sifting out just what the difference you're trying to call out is, and why it matters/was done that way. For some concrete examples: "the only thing you know [with the type family] is that you get `Constraint` after applying two type variables"; what extra thing do you know with the type class? What are you trying to illustrate with your `Functor` analogy? What is "pattern matching on variables", why is it useful for GHC to be able to do it, and what do you give up by allowing it?

Comment: This answer is wrong on multiple accounts. 1. Type classes ARE NOT types, they are classes of types, as per the name. 2. Overlapping type classes are equivalent to non-injective type families: In an overlapping type class, it is possible that a type matches with the heads of two separate type class instances of the same type class. 3. By pattern matching, I think that you mean that the type system tries to find the most specific type class instance according to algorithms laid out in the specification and GHC, for overlapping instances.